# How can you implement these two heap constructors using a comparator?

Tags: java, heap, comparator

I've never messed with comparators before and I'm struggling to grasp the concept enough to implement it as a heap. Especially since I couldn't find anything online involving both comparators and heaps together. As far as my knowledge, here is the code you will need. Let me know if anything else is needed. Thanks.

```
//A complete tree stored in an array list representing this binary heap

private ArrayList<E> tree;

// A comparator lambda function that compares two elements of this heap when rebuilding it

private Constructor<? super E> cmp;

// constructs an empty heap using the compareTo method of its data type  as the comparator

public Heap () {

}

// A parameterized constructor that uses an externally defined comparator
  
// @param fn - a trichotomous integer value comparator function

public Heap(Comparator<? super E> fn) {

}
```

Correct me if I'm wrong, but in order to use the comparator, you will need the compareTo method which is the natural comparison method. This compareTo method is of class Car and you can find information about that below. Here is the compareTo method:

```
public int CompareTo(Car c) {
   
   if (year != c.year) 
     return year - c.year; 
   if(make.compareTo(c.make) != 0) 
     return make.compareTo(c.make); 
   if(make.compareTo(c.model) != 0) 
     return model.compareTo(c.model);
   return type.compareTo(c.type);
```

**You may or may not need this information to help me to implement these two heap constructors:**

The overall goal of what I'm trying to do is to implement the main method that takes in the name of a data file and a numeric code representing the sort key (or the order the data is to be sorted using the heap). And then generate a sorted list of the data. In this specific case, I am sorting cars with the following order codes:

-2 (-make-model-type-year )
, -1 (-year-make-mode-type)
), 0 (-type+year-makemodel),
1 (+year+make+model+type) and 2 (+make+model+type+year )

The + sign indicates ascending order and the - sign indicates descending
order.

Comment: You don't need to use the `compareTo` method to use the comparator.  Instead of writing `a.compareTo(b)`, you just write `cmp.compare(a, b)`.

Comment: I think you're mixing up `Comparator`, which is a separate object for making order comparisons on whatever type the comparator accepts, and `Comparable`, which is an interface that some objects implement in order to get "natural" ordering behavior with methods that accept `Comparable`s as input: sorting for example.

Comment: Make that `compareTo`, not `CompareTo`. Add `@Override` annotation to detect such errors.

Answer (score 0):

As [Gene commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69428076/how-can-you-implement-these-two-heap-constructors-using-a-comparator/69428621#comment122714658_69428076), you seem to be conflating [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html) and [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html).  The first notes that a class carries a `compareTo` method so objects of that class can sort themselves. The second indicates a class is a separate class that knows how to sort objects of a certain other class.

Generally best to use the latter (`Comparator`) if you want different sorting in various situations. Use the first (`Comparable`) when you have only a single specific sorting algorithm.

When using a `Comparator`, the objects being sorted need not be `Comparable`.

In modern Java, [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html) was enhanced with some convenient methods for building a comparator.

```
Comparator
    .comparingInt( Car :: getYear )
    .thenComparing( Car :: getMake )
    .thenComparing( Car :: getModel() )
```

Rather than use a `List`, use a `NavigableSet` such as `TreeSet` to keep objects sorted.

```
NavigableSet< Car > cars = new TreeSet<>( myComparator ) ;
```

I do not understand the logic shown in the last section of your Question, so perhaps I’ve misunderstood the true nature of your query.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation between the two. I was mixing them up. This is a project I am working on where I, unfortunately, can't alter the code given to me. I'm also new to programming so that's why the explanation in the post might not make a ton of sense. But I can see now that apparently the code given to me uses both a comparator and comparable, at least I think. For example, the heap class I'm trying to implement is defined as such: "public class Heap<E extends Comparable<E>> implements HeapAPI<E>" but  within the class there is, " private Comparator <? super E> cmp;"